# Spring RestTemplate API query parameter encoding for doing a GET HTTP Request

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, get, resttemplate

The url-string contains a back-slash character that needs to be encoded. The url string is as follows.

```
    String folder = "\\Foo\\Bar\\"; // some folder search path.
    String urlString= "http://localhost:8081/certificates/?mypath=%5CFoo%5CBar%5C" // (after encoding)
```

Here I use Spring RestTemplate to do a GET request. I setup a mock-server to examine the request in detail (mock server setup using Mulesoft, if u must know!).

```
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = api.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()), String.class);
```

[image: examining GET request produced by Spring's RestTemplate]

Here I use plain vanilla Java URLConnection to perform the request. Attached image with detailed request snapshot.

```
    // 2. Plain vanilla java URLConnection. "result.toString()" has certificate match.
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Venafi-Api-Key", apiKey);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

[image: examining GET request produced by vanilla Java]

In the images, you can see that the **queryString** value is different for these two requests. One of them shows **\\** while the other shows **%5C**, although the parsed parameter value for *myPath* is still the same.

I am having to deal with an api that seems to work if-and-only-if the queryString looks like the former (i.e. **"\\"**). Why does the parsed queryString for Spring show "%5C" while this value shows double-backslash for requests originating from plain Java, curl, and even a simple browser?

What baffles me **EVEN** more, is that just about everything about the two HTTP Requests are **IDENTICAL**! And yet, why does the queryString/requestUri parse differently for these two requests? Shouldn't it be that a HTTP GET method is completely defined by its header contents and the requestUri? What am I missing to capture in these two GET requests?

Lots of questions. Spent an entire day, but at least I could verify that the way the **requestUri/queryString** is parsed seems to align with how the remote api-server responds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging around the following morning. Turn out, with

```
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = api.exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()), String.class);
```

You should **NOT** have the **"urlString"** already encoded. The 'exchange' method does that encoding for you under-the-hood.